# jquery plugin $.extend

Tags: jquery, plugins, namespaces, extend

if i extend the jquery `fn`(like $.fn.extend) i write my plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        functionName : function(){
             //function returns
             return this.each(function(){
                  $(this).append("<div>text</div>");
             });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

when i want to extend jQuery namespace i write it like this:

```
(function($){
    $.extend({
        functionName : function(){
             //function returns

        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

what i don't know is how to write the 'return' in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

When you are doing multiple operations involving more than one selector, you have to decide what makes the most sense. If one selector is the primary focus, but effects other items as well, write it like a plugin, and return the primary result set like this:

```
$.fn.myAction = function(secondarySelector){
      return this.each(function(){
          $(this).css('display', 'block');
          $(secondarySelector).hide();
      });
};

// Use:
// $(primarySelector).myAction(secondarySelector);
$("#id").myAction(".address"); // Chain continues after action
```

If the selectors are all equal in importance, then simply create a function that does not return anything or returns `true` / `false` depending on success.

**Another way to structure the code:**

The extend method is used in other OOP frameworks and as you have shown, can be used with jQuery as well. What you will find, however, is many jQuery developers opt for the shorter more obvious syntax like this:

```
(function($){

    // The if statement allows the file to be used with
    // other files that use the same shared namespace
    if(!$.Namespace){
        $.Namespace = { };
    };

    $.Namespace.Constructor = function( params ){
       ... code ...
    };

    // And for the wrapper sets ($.fn):
    $.fn.functionName = function(opts){
       return this.each(function(){
          ... code ...
       });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: so for what i want to do i don't need the "return" keyword anymore?(like return this.each())

Comment: @kmunky I added an answer to how to possibly handle that. Does it make sense for you particular needs?

Comment: pff..hard to say. i thinks that my problem is not this one. i will come with a new question, thanks for this great post

Answer (score 2):

You can return whatever you like in the second instance. Forexample think of `$.each()` versus `$.get()`. However, if i were you i would avoid using this as a function namespace - it can lead to pollution. Instead you shoudl reserve this for add your own namespace under the jquery namespace like:

```
(function($){
    $.extend({
        myNamspace : {
          functionName: function(){
            // return whatever
          }
        }
    }});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: ok, but i am interested in that 'return whatever'; how should i write it? if i want to return just one line like 'return $(selector).append(...)' it works just like this...but how should i write it if i want to return multiple 'actions' like '$(selectorOne).appned(); $(slectorTwo).remove();'

Comment: then return an array, object, or jquery node list. but what to return depends on waht you want your function to return.