# When should I use $.fn.extend() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie in jQuery. Some jQuery plugins use `$.fn.extend()`, which I've seen in [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/) documentation, but I don't understand when I should use it or how.

I've seen it used in the plugin [skitter-slider](http://www.skitter-slider.net/). I really want to know how to use it.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery plugin $.extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898402/jquery-plugin-extend)

Comment: Hint: learn how to use [so], it's easy: [help]

Comment: @Yogesh, yes I read it but on this line: "The jQuery.fn.extend() method extends the jQuery prototype ($.fn) object to provide new methods that can be chained to the jQuery() function.", I'm lost.

Comment: Which part of that line confuses you? Do you understand what javascript prototype is?

Comment: "...provide new methods that can be chained to the jQuery() function". What method it means? I've never use protopype into my codes, but according to this [definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_string.asp), we use it to add a property to an object.

Comment: The documentation you linked to shows an example. In there, `$.fn.extend` is called and passed an object with the two functions `check` and `uncheck`. Later in the example you can see how `check` is called on a jQuery object. Hence, `check` and `uncheck` are the "new methods" that have been added to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I will use it and how

When you want to **merge** objects. For example you have

```
var A = {
   foo: 42
};
```

and

```
var B = {
   bar: 21;
};
```

Now you want to merge `B` into `A`, to create

```
var A = {
   foo: 42,
   bar: 21
};
```

This is done by

```
$.extend(A, B);
```

Comment: I know how to use $.extend() but my problem is how to use jQuery.fn.extend if I create OOP jQuery plugins

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and explain your problem properly. Also include some example code. And FYI, `$.extend` and `$.fn.extend` are one and the same function.

Comment: With $.extend we can merge 2 functions and with $.fn.extend we can do the same...I understand, thank you!

Comment: Objects, not functions.

Comment: Do you have a link or example that can help me when I should use $.fn.extend instead of $.extend?

Comment: There is no reason to use one over the other, because they are exactly the same function. `$.fn.extend === $.extend` returns `true`. Personally I would always use `$.extend` because I have to type less characters.

Comment: This is one example: $.fn.extend({init: function() {...} });, therefore, equivalent to this is: $.extend({init:function() {...}})?

Comment: Oh, apparently I was wrong `$.fn.extend` is actually different than `$.extend`. As it says in the documentation: *"Merge the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods."*. So `$.fn.extend({init: function() {...} });` is equivalent to `$.extend($.fn, {init: function() {...}});`.

Comment: Jquery extend and jquery fn extend is not one and the same. Jquery extend is to extend existing objects with other objects. However,jquery fn.extend is used to extend jquery namespace with new functions and plugins that can chain directly eith jqueries selector functions.

Comment: @Yogesh: That's what I just said in my previous comment ;) Nonetheless, `$.fn.extend === $.extend` is really `true`, so under the hood, jQuery uses the same function for that. I would delete the while answer, but I can't :-/

Comment: Sorry,I was typing in my comment before you posted your comment.but I am happy that you found the difference. I didnt mean to offend you.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if you have any plugin with configuration, you may set's default values and supplement this with $.extend

Look at this:

```
(function ($) {

    $.superPlugin = {

        // plugin defaults
        defaults: 
        {
            mainClass: 'node',
            orientation: 'vertical',
            focusEvent: function (event) {
                console.log('Focus!');
            }
        };
    };

    // plugin code
    $.fn.superPlugin = function (fn, options) {

        var config = $.extend( true, {}, $.setSelect.defaults, options );

        /**
         *  results: { 
         *      mainClass: 'node', 
         *      orientation: 'horizontal', 
         *      focusEvent: function (event) {
         *         console.log('Custom focus event!');
         *      }
         *  }
         */
    };

})(jQuery);

// custom config
var options = {
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    focusEvent: function (event) {
        console.log('Custom focus event!')
    }
}

// bind plugin to element
$('.item').superPlugin(options);
```

Comment: This is a good eXample but fails to explain the difference